# Having a react native mobile app along with angular2 web app

Tags: angular, react-native

I currently have my web app using angular2 (now 5 technically). It seemed like an easier starting point for me coming from an object-oriented background and am quite happy with the entire web development process with angular. My service is related to financial services with data tables, input forms, etc but not very graphics intensive.

Now, I am getting started with a cross-platform mobile app and naturally the first step was to explore nativescript as it enables use of angular2 code. I do like the ability to share code and logic, but nativescript's smaller community, fewer plugins, some other UI limitations have made me think that I should maybe think of react native. I looked at Ionic but would prefer not to have a hybrid app.

React native seems to be a pretty solid choice with significant use in production by even larger companies, whereas for nativescript I can't find any really great apps produced. These apps also seem to be very smooth and almost indistinguishable from native apps. Looking at any apps from the nativescript showcases, I always found that there was some difference in performance and feel from native.

My question now is that is it advisable to have two different frameworks for my web app and mobile app? I understand that the learning curve is different for react and it follows a completely different philosophy than angular in terms of data binding but I am open to learning that and maintaining the two projects separately. Just wanted to see people's thoughts on this, whether this is done often, etc.

Comment: I don't think so. When you pick a framework to develop with, you should follow its rules. If you start creating an application using two distinguished frameworks such as angular and react, it's gonna be really hard to follow only one convention.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, though this is only the front-end view. Angular will be used for the web app and react native will be used for the mobile app, so they won't really be used together at all. The backend server is the same to be used for both. Just wondering how big are the code sharing / shared testing advantages and does it hurt one developer to learn two different frameworks

Comment: As long as you keep them seperate, it shouldn't matter. However, using the same set of tools will allow you to be faster, in terms of knowledge acquisition and possibly allow you to share some of the code.

Comment: Yes agreed, that is definitely a fair point. Maybe I will use react native for mobile and later think about converting the web version as well. Its just that the web version has already been created in angular and I'm quite happy with it and face no issues currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO I believe having two different frameworks for web and mobile is fine, ultimately it depends on the developer himself.

However, in each and every different framework, take `ReactJS` as example, has different life cycle principles to respect. And this is perhaps something you can take advantage on both `ReactJS` and `React-Native` because they both follow the same philosophy.

Instead of spending more time learning different frameworks shallowly, why not dig deeper in just one?

Just my 2 cents, hope it helps :)

Comment: My web app has already been created in Angular and would love to use it for mobile as well. But nativescript limitations feel like I will have to compromise on UI/design which I really don't want to do. I also really like the larger community of react-native vs nativescript and its use by many big companies. Do you think I should try and convert my web app to react as well? I was thinking that I can start with the react-native mobile app and later down the line if I like react a lot, maybe convert the web version to reactJS. What do you think? Thanks again

Comment: If you already have your web-app created with Angular then why not just stay it that way? I would convert only if there's some circumstances where Angular cannot satisfy. But for the long run, I would personally use react-js for both web and mobile.

Comment: Yup, completely agree. Will only convert web from angular to react if really needed or if I find the reactive framework much better. One thing I'm doing to keep it similar between the two is use as many reactive forms in angular rather than template-driven so that I'm used to the one-way data binding

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t mix 2 different frameworks, your going to confuse yourself down the line. I would stick to just stick with angular. There’s more tutorials and a bigger community than react.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have a pretty good understanding of angular2 and would love to use it for the native app as well but it is just the nativescript limitations that are drawing me to react-native. The community for angular web version is great, but when it comes to mobile, the nativescript community and third party plugin support seem to be much smaller than react-native. Please let me know if I am incorrect. I agree that the frameworks are fairly different and it can get confusing but if I don't want to sacrifice UI/design which I think nativescript will force me to, what do you suggest?